# Angular2 observable http get conditional repeat

Tags: angular, http, get, rxjs, observable

I'm using angular2 observable pattern to make http requests.
I'm trying to conditional repeat the http get: I want to execute the http get until a condition is met:

```
http.get('url')
.map(res => {
     // if the condition is met I should repeat the http get request
})
.subscribe()
```

Is there a way to conditional repeat the http get request?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: I would say you could use a recursive function for this

Comment: Hi Mike, can you explain me how can i do it with observable please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [expand](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/3f1218340510006a11b93c0c8ae853ac2d2b0121/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md) operator. Here's an example:

```js
let request$ = http.get('url');

request$.expand(value => {
  return value !== 0 ? request$ : Rx.Observable.empty()
})
.map(res => {
  //Do mapping here
})
.subscribe()
```