# Make Recursive calls using http.get() in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular4-httpclient

I have a scenario where the initial request will send a url path and the subsequent request should make use of that path as the url to be hit using get request from service. (*This part is done*)

Now the actual issue starts , the problem here is that the ***2nd*** request will not give the output directly rather it will send the status as *QUEUE* until the response is fully processed. All I have to do is to wait/hit the url again until *QUEUE* state is changed to *OK* state (Actual response comes here).

Code for 2nd request :

getOriginalData(url:any){

```
  const proxyRequest=this._getRequest(url)

  return proxyRequest
  .expand(response => {
      if (response.uuid==null) {
        this._getRequest(url);
      } else {
        Rx.Observable.empty();
      }
    return Observable.of(response);
  });

private _getRequest(url:any){
  return this._http.get(url)
}
```

I have been following this implementation to achieve my goal : [Angular - Correctly using RXJS expand operator to make recursive http calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981974/angular-correctly-using-rxjs-expand-operator-to-make-recursive-http-calls) .

Using this implementation results in

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

But for some reason , it is not working as expected. How can I make a recursive call in a standard way such that it doesn't flood the network.

Answer (score 1):

Never used expand operator but from what I've understand you need to return an Observable.empty to stop the recursive request

Comment: But the request gets failed due to Stack error though

Comment: You haven't returned the observable.empty so the expand didn't stop

Comment: I have changed it as follows `getOriginalData(url:any){

      const proxyRequest=this._getRequest(url)

      return proxyRequest
      .expand(response => {
          if (response.uuid==null) {
           return this._getRequest(url);
          } else {
           return Rx.Observable.empty();
          }
      });`  But its kind of going on forever without getting the final output

Comment: So try to debug to look what response is returning. Maybe response.uuid is always null and the function keep going to call http request