# Repeat Request based on data result

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi I'm new to angular and I want to know what is the right way of repeating GET request based on the resulting data.

**item.service.ts**

```
ScanItems():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(url)     
}
```

**item.component.ts**

```
GetScannedItems(){
   this.ScanSubscription = this.itemService.ScanItems()
    .subscribe(
       data => {
         RDate = new Date(data.Date).getTime();
         const NDate = new Date().getTime();
         const Diff = RDate - NDate
         if(Diff > (-300000)){
           console.log('Valid')
         }
         else {
           // Repeat Request Here!!!
         }
       },
       error => console.error(error),
       () => this.ScanSubscription.unsubscribe()
   )
}
```

Comment: one option is to go traditional recursive call approach or another option is rxjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981974/angular-correctly-using-rxjs-expand-operator-to-make-recursive-http-calls

Comment: which one is a better practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of handling in component, you can do this in service with retry operator.

```
GetScannedItems(){
   this.ScanSubscription = this.itemService.ScanItems()
    .pipe(
      map(
       data => {
         RDate = new Date(data.Date).getTime();
         const NDate = new Date().getTime();
         const Diff = RDate - NDate
         if(Diff > (-300000)){
           return of(true);
         }
         else {
            return Observable.throw('retry');
           // Repeat Request Here!!!
         }
       }),
       delay(500),
       retry()
   )
}
```

Comment: Don't make assumption.I think OP question is little bit different. He was asking a recursive approach. Retry will always send the same request again

Comment: its a repeat request as per the title

Comment: updated. check whether it works. or else we need to use flatMap

Comment: thanks a lot, i've change `return Observable.throw()` to just `throw()`